# Faces disappearing when in Wireframe and in STL export

Tags: wireframe

So bit of a newb here.  I have started to design a phone holder that will be later 3D printed.
I have basically used cube meshes and have bevelled the edges.  I though i would export it as an STL to do a test 3d print just to make sure all was good and noticed alot of the faces were missing. As if the shaped were not solid..  Any ideas on what i did wrong?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Are you in solid mode? it's hard to tell without a screenshot of your settings and UI. Add some screenshots of that to have more information of the issue

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse,  I will add a screenshot of the UI.  Basically all i have done is added cube meshes, extruded/scaled. Highlighted edges and Ctrl-B with 100 segments. From here my plan was to join the meshes and export as stl, however this did not work well and i can see in wireframe mode it does not appear to be solid. I will attach a picture of the STL once i have imported it to sketchup just to view

Comment: You say you joined them. Understand that Blender has a terminology, and it matters whether you did what Blender refers to as "joining" or if you instead combined the shapes some other way, such as by using a Boolean Union operation, because these functions are very different. If you really did use the join command, that's your problem. Joining is a bit of a misnomer. Joined objects are almost better thought of as being grouped, because they aren't actually fused together, and can be separated easily. I believe a join operation could very likely cause any 3D printing effort to fail.